# Create Outlook email in non-default folder

Tags: delphi, email, outlook

I'm trying to create an Outlook email in a non-default folder using Delphi:

```pascal
procedure NewMail;
var
  ParentFolder, Myfolder:  MAPIFolder;
  MyMail: MailItem;

begin
  Parentfolder := MAPI.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent as MAPIFolder;
  MyFolder := ParentFolder.Folders.Item('MyMessages') as MAPIFolder;
  MyMail := MyFolder.Items.Add(olMailItem) as MailItem;
  MyMail.Save;
  MyMail.Display(false);
end;
```

The mail item is displayed, but does not appear in the non-default folder. The folder is good (I can copy emails to it manually, and get items.count programatically). If I use the same code for a non-default tasks folder it works fine, so it appears to be something particular about an email folder.   Grateful for any suggestions.  Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook has an annoying habit of creating messages in the default folder even if you explicitly specify a different folder. Try to move the message there:

```
MyMail := MyFolder.Items.Add(olMailItem) as MailItem;
MyMail := MyMail.Move(MyFolder);
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry.  Your suggestion puts the message in the desired folder, but when the user tries to send the message Outlook complains that it has been deleted.  What remains in the folder is a draft of the message with nothing in any of the fields.  Perhaps the best approach is an event sink in the sent items folder, but I have heard that that uses up a lot of overhead.

Comment: I had misread your code, and typed:    MyMail := MyFolder.Items.Add(olMailItem) as MailItem;    MyMail.Move(Myfolder);  When I use your code exactly, it appears to have no effect - the email is still in the sent items folder, and does not appear in the custom folder.  I solved the problem by addin g code to the Items.Add event of the sent items folder, and copying and moving the email from there.  Thanks as always for your help.  Paul